# Ethernet is connected to Debian server running on my laptop but I don't get an IP address

Tags: networking, ethernet, file-server

I plugged Ethernet to Debian server running as a Virtual Machine on my laptop through VMware Workstation. The cable, router and modem are perfectly working but I can't connect and I don't get an IP address.

When I entered `ip a` for knowing IP address. the result was given below:

```
root@openmediavault: "# ip address

1: 10: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred 1ft forever
    inet6:1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: ens33: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:cc:72:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@openmediavault:"#
```

What can I do?

Comment: yes, and i have installed  in virtual machine and in  another machine i directly installed in  it  without virtual machine Debian server .In both of these systems i can' cannot connect to internet and doesn't have Ip on both of these machines

Comment: VMware workstation

Comment: Please don't put information in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question to add it there. I've done it twice for you now. Next time please do it yourself. This makes it easy for people to see everything about your issue so they can help you

Comment: What can I do? You can read something like
  https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-6F7ECBA6-A29A-40AE-B565-3D0F2E74FEA4.html